# Error with Php-form with checkboxes

Tags: php, google-chrome, windows-xp

I have made a php-page that has a form and checkboxes and method POST. 
On windows 7 with Internet Explorer it work perfect. On a different computer with Windows XP with Google Chrome it does not work. The form is of type submit and the action takes place in a method in the same php-file.

Do anyone know if there is some special problems with php on chrome or php on windows xp that can mess things up.

Here is the form

```
<form name='test' method='POST' action='' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<input type="hidden" name="bandnamn" value="<?php echo $bn; ?>" />  
Description and info about the band:<br>
<input type='text' name='bandtext' size='50'><br>

//plus 7 more inputs of type text simular to the one on top of this

Category 1:<br>
<?php 
     $query="SELECT id, kategori FROM punkkategorier"; 
$result = mysql_query ($query);
echo "<select name=kategori1 value=''></option>";                   while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
     echo "<option value=$nt[id]>$nt[kategori]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>

//and 2 more Category checkboxes

<br><br>
<input type='submit' name='Submit2' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

And here is the Submit part.

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit2']))
{
$host='localhost'; // Host name 
$username="myusername"; // Mysql username 
$password="mypassword"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="dbname"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="mytablename"; // Table name 



// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
mysql_set_charset('utf8');

//A MYSQL_QUERY WITH A SELECTSTATEMENT

$result =mysql_query("select id from punkband where bandnamn = '".$_POST['bandnamn']."'");
if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
{
    $show_form=1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $hiddenbandnamn= $row['id'];
    }
}

}
```

$show_form=1 means it is correct and the next page viewed will be the right one, if $show_form does not change to =1 the next page will be wrong. On  Windows 7 with IE it works perfect. On Windows XP with Google Chrome it does not work.

Comment: PHP does not run in Chrome. It runs in a web server. Your output HTML might be invalid. We can't tell without seeing code.

Comment: Also, please return to your earlier questions and accept answers where appropriate. You'll get better & swifter help in the future.

Comment: Post some of your code. In order to get values you need to have [] in the name if there is more than one.

Comment: What is the value of `$bn`?  If it causes invalid HTML in some browsers, it won't be posted with the form, and your query won't succeed.

Comment: Also, on your form handler, you have opened your script to SQL injection attacks. Please filter `$_POST['bandnamn']`:  use `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bandnamn'])` in your query.

Comment: The $bn is a name, if that would be incorrect in any way it would not work on either winxp win7 ie or chrome later in the program. The only thing that can be specific with $bn is that it can contain special characters (swedish åäö etc)

Comment: And also, you should specify what exactly does not work. Do you receive a php error or does the form not submit?

Comment: @bajenmicke Encode `$bn` in the form input. Different browsers may handle it differently:  `<?php echo htmlentities($bn, ENG_QUOTES); ?>`

Comment: Kristian hildebrandt, what is going wrong exactly I dont know, a user of the program sent a error mail to me and just told me that he was sent to the wrong page after submiting the form. There is no output on the page just navigating to the wrong page.

Comment: Michael, I think that was what I was looking for, gonna try the htmlentities. thanks.

Comment: @bajenmicke I added that info as an answer below. Please accept it if it works for you.  Also, in comments prepend a username with `@` so we are auto-notified that someone has replied to us directly. You'll get a faster response.

Answer (score 0):

You form may be incorrectly submitting, depending on the contents of `$bn` in the hidden input.  You need to wrap the contents of the variable in `htmlentities()` to encode it.

```
<input type="hidden" name="bandnamn" value="<?php echo htmlentities($bn, ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
```

Comment: I use specialcharacters like swedish "åäö" etc, if i use htmlentities the åäö will be shown incorrect.